# Pagination for responsive e-commerce website

Tags: usability, e-commerce, pagination, responsive

I'm working on the pagination topic for a responsive project. I'd like to have some feedbacks from you regarding this solution.

**Scenario**:

- pagination for the search results page;
- pagination for category listing page;
- we can't use infinite scroll because we have on the top of the listing (different adv for each pages) the special offers from our sellers (they pay for this feature);

**Questions**:

- make sense to hide the page numbers in the XS view;
- make sense to hide the prev and next links when the user is in the first/last page?

**Mockups:**

[image: Normal views]

[image: Normal views]

Comment: Both your mockups seem to be the same image (although different filenames). Can you check these are correct and replace if necessary? Also, for reference - StackExchange uses [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), not html for markup in posts.

Comment: Sorry for that, I updated the images

Answer (score 1):

Also in the SM, MD, LG Pagination you could remove one number in both ends having:

```
< Prev  1 2 ... 79 80  Next >
```

Instead of:

```
< Prev  1 2 3 ... 78 79 80  Next >
```

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with both your questions.

Rather than full removal of the numbers perhaps you could replace the numbers with a drop down on mobile devices possibly.

This would allow people who wish to jump to a specific page the ability to still do this.

You could also only show the page numbers (links or dropdown) if the number of results is more than 2 or 3 pages.

Comment: Hi Stephen We've got a lot of pages for our categories. Our platform is for buying and bidding and the search results page is very crowded.